# Redirect http to https using Symfony

Tags: apache, symfony, .htaccess, http, https

I'm sorry to post a new question for something that has been asked many times but none of the answers I found worked for me.
I have a site in Symfony and I want it to use HTTPS and not HTTP, so I want to redirect the URLs.
For this, I have a .htaccess file in the public:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And another in the racine, I've tried multiple things but none worked, here are some of my tests:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myurl [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?10.16.10.164)$ [NC]

RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure to understand right all of these and this is maybe why I'm not able to make it work.

There is other information you will maybe need:
My apache conf has this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location "/">
        Redirect permanent "https://%{HTTP_HOST}:8000%{REQUEST_URI}"    
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https:/myurl/$1 [NE,L,R=301
</VirtualHost>
```

I have this in my security.yaml:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, requires_channel: https}
```

In my framework.yaml:

```
trusted_proxies: '192.0.0.1,10.0.0.0/8, myurl'
# trust *all* "X-Forwarded-*" headers
trusted_headers: ['x-forwarded-for', 'x-forwarded-host', 'x- 
forwarded-proto', 'x-forwarded-port', 'x-forwarded-prefix']
# or, if your proxy instead uses the "Forwarded" header
trusted_headers: ['forwarded']
```

I also created a certificate but I read somewhere that it's not a good way to do it with Symfony so I'm not using it. I did this because my error is: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

And what I want is to redirect all HTTP to HTTPS and the:8000 to be automatically added.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: So this is your own server and you are serving HTTPS on port 8000? Does a request for `https://example.com:8000/` work? "I also created a certificate but I read somewhere that it's not a good way to do it with Symfony" - You need an SSL cert to implement HTTPS - irrespective of whether you are using Symfony or any other framework?

Comment: Thanks for your response @MrWhite.
Yes, this is my own server and I'm using port 8000 and want to use HTTPS.
And a request to this URL will give me: "This site cannot provide a secure connection"
Yes, I need SSL cert but since I had it idk where to put it

Comment: Ah, so this is an SSL cert/server configuration issue, not a "redirect" issue (as you are detailing in most of your question). Unfortunately this is probably off-topic on StackOverflow. [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) might be a better fit, but you will need to provide more detail about your server config. As far as the "redirect" is concerned, something like your first `<VirtualHost *:80>` container should be all that's required, except you can't use server variables in the `Redirect` directive and don't need the `<Location>` wrapper.

Comment: Ok, thank you @MrWhite I'm going to post a question here and I'll look to every details that I can post on it :)